# Thingsboard Dashboard Entities table with Entity Views

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

This issue is very similar to [Thingsboard Dashboard Custom Action NullInjectorError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62341426/5239616)

I setup Entities table widget with Datasources from Entity alias like "Entity Views of type 'power_sensor'".

The idea is simple:

- if Entity View's name is "Powermeter1" - then goto Dashboard state 1
- else if it is called "Powermeter2" - goto Dashboard state 2

Now I'm going to create Custom action for “On row click ” but fail. I rty to modify @lee-sangjun's code according to [entity.service API](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/13e6b10b7ab830e64d31b99614a9d95a1a25928a/ui-ngx/src/app/core/http/entity.service.ts#L64) like this:

```
var $injector = widgetContext.$scope.$injector;

$injector.get(widgetContext.entityService.get('entityViewService')).getEntity(entityId.id).subscribe(function(entity) {
        if (entity.name == 'Powermeter1') {
            openDashboardState('energy_state_1')
        }
        else if(entity.name == 'Powermeter2') {
            openDashboardState('water_state_2')
        }
});

function openDashboardState(stateId) {
    var params = {
        entityId: entityId,
        entityName: entityName
    }

    widgetContext.stateController.openState(stateId, params,
        false);
}
```

But nothing happens. What I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution I've found:

```
var $injector = widgetContext.$scope.$injector;

$injector.get(widgetContext.servicesMap.get('entityViewService')).getEntityView(entityId.id).subscribe(function(entity) {
    console.log(entity)
    if (entity.name == 'Powermeter1') {
        openDashboardState('energy_state_1')
    }
    else if(entity.name == 'Powermeter2') {
        openDashboardState('water_state_2')
    }
});

function openDashboardState(stateId) {
    var params = {
        entityId: entityId,
        entityName: entityName
    }

    widgetContext.stateController.openState(stateId, params,
        false);
}
```

Where 'Powermeter1' and 'Powermeter2' are names of Entity Views. Hope it will be helpful.